# UIImagePickerController Apple TV Screen Mirroring Issue

Tags: ios, swift, apple-tv, airplay

I have an app that is designed primarily to run with an Apple TV using screen mirroring. Generally it runs fine with no issues at all.

There are points in the app where I load a camera using

```
UIImagePickerController()
```

Majority of the time the camera screens loads fine, no issues however occasionally on the Apple TV get the error "An error occurred loading this content.     Try again later." with the yellow triangle error symbol.

The app continues to run fine on the iPad but the Screen Mirroring link has gone.

I load the camera by:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
imagePicker.mediaTypes = options
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerController.QualityType.typeMedium
imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 59
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

'Options' being a string array of allowable media i.e.

```
[kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Is there:
a) Anything obvious I can do in code (swift) to make 'Screen Mirroring' more stable?
b) Is there any known issues with UIImagePickerController and Apple TV 'Screen Mirroring'?
c) From within code is it possible I can check screen mirroring has broke and reconnect?

Thanks